# The set of points on a line is equinumerous with the set of points on a plane

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me to construct a proof of this fact? I'm having a difficult time understanding how to prove that two sets are of the same size.

Comment: See for instance http://planetmath.org/bijectionbetweenunitintervalandunitsquare

Answer (score 1):

Is a classic: see p 22 of [these notes by Eric Schechter](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/infinity.pdf).

Alternative form: use a [space-filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) and [Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem).
‎